# Convergence/Divergence $\int_2^\infty \frac{4x^3+3x^2-x}{5x^5-2x^4+x^2-2}\ln x \, dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{4x^3+3x^2-x}{5x^5-2x^4+x^2-2}\ln x\, dx$$

How should I approach this? can I look at $$\int_2^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2}\,dx \text{?}$$

Comment: Use `\ln x`for $\ln x$ instead.

Comment: You should also check that the integrand doesn't diverge in the interval $[2, \infty)$, that is, whether the denominator has any root there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand function is bounded between $\frac{4\log x}{5 x^2}$ and $\frac{84\log x}{65 x^2}$ on the interval $(2,+\infty)$, hence the integral is converging since
$$ \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{1+\log 2}{2}.$$

Comment: How do you find the bounded functions?

Comment: @newhere: by just studying $\frac{4x^5+3x^4-x^3}{5x^5-2x^4+x^2-2}$ over $(2,+\infty)$, but that constants are not that important. The integrand function is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{\log x}{x^2}$ that is an integrable function, so the original integral is convergent.

Comment: Great answer! I must press further though... How did you get the upper bound $\frac{84\log x}{65 x^2}$? I don't see an obvious way to show this, though I must be missing something blatant. I can't see how you got those coefficients

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: the previous function in my comment is decreasing on $(2,+\infty)$, the constant $\frac{84}{65}$ just comes from evaluating it at $x=2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ah,  that makes perfect sense. Thank you for the clarification!